# Validate a java.util.Map against a XML schema (No XML document only a Map Object)

Tags: validation, xsd, dictionary

This may be a weird question, but recently i am thinking of something like validating a map object having key- value pairs from an xsd. I mean if xsd have a two elements like foo and bar under some root element and a map contains key - value pairs like foo = "me" and bar = 123, i should be able to validate this map against corresponding xsd without transforming the map into xml/json or anything model sort of thing. i have done some search but couldnt find any api supporting this. Also i looked into javax.xml.validation api but i couldnt figure out that how exactly the Validator validates the xml against xsd. If somehow i can get properties of each element from the xsd and then maybe i will be able to validate the map. Please give me some information regarding this, any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I could imagine a validator that worked by handling SAX events; you could imagine sending those events based on the data in your map. This is a mechanism by which a third-party validator could be used. Not that I know of any validators that work that way.

Comment: Note that one Map would surely not be sufficient; it would be a map containing nested submaps, yes?

Comment: Probably yes,but if i can extract property of each element including complex types from the xml schema and then use it to validate elements present in map; nothing like it . Could you explain more about SAX Events, it might help me making this thing work.

Comment: A "SAX parser" reads an XML document and generates a series of events -- i.e., calls a series of methods -- to describe the document. You implement those methods to do something; I'm imagining a validator which implemented the methods to validate the document. In Java, you implement the methods by extending org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler. See for example, here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML